# Can not login team foundation server(TFS), good through web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

i get problem on login to TFS.

I can login through the web interface, and OK on another computer.

But on my laptop , when i use the Visual Studio 2012, Team--> connect to TFS...

after entering user name and password,it go to this screen and wait forever...

[image]

I get window 7 and IE 11,
someone tell me TFS get problem these days....

Comment: do you always connect to the same TFS, or to different ones from time to time?

Comment: Do you perhaps have IE8 and are trying to connect to VSO? Coz VSO no longer supports IE8...I say that as my current customer has IE8 and I have seen the some thing.